# jquery deactivate function when another is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a search function on my webpage. Currently i have my working code

```
search.click(function () {
    search.attr("src", "Icons/magnifier.png").css({
        "border": "2px",
        "border-style": "solid",
        "border-color": "#000000",
        "padding-left": "130px",
        "transition": "all 500ms"
    });
});
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'search') {
        $("#search").attr("src", "Icons/magnifier2.png");
        $("#search").css({
            "border": "2px",
            "border-style": "solid",
            "border-color": "#c8c8c8",
            "padding-left": "4px",
            "transition": "all 500ms"
        });
    }
});
```

what this function does, is that when its clicked the icon changes and the border expands to the left, Whereafter when the user clicks on the page it goes back to normal.

Right now i want to add a hover function to it that highlights the button.

i got following:

```
 var search = $("#search");
 search.mouseover(function (event) {
     search.css({
         "border": "2px",
         "border-style": "solid",
         "border-color": "#808080",
         "padding-left": "4px",
         "transition": "all 500ms"
     });
 });

 search.mouseout(function (event) {
     if (event != ('clicked')) {
         search.css({
             "border": "2px",
             "border-style": "solid",
             "border-color": "#c8c8c8",
             "padding-left": "4px",
             "transition": "all 500ms"
         });
     }
 });
```

The icon acts as i want it when i hover. However, if i click on it, it expands, but if i move my mouse away from the field, my mouseout function fires.. I tried to do a conditional expression, but i know its wrong, the hover function should not be active when the border is expanded, how do i go about that? 
As im new, and trying to learn this, i would really appreciate an explanation based on the answers.

https://jsfiddle.net/g2aLwLhg/

Comment: On click, you should add a class (which btw could define the style to apply). And check it for `hover` methods. Now, you should provide a jsFiddle e.g, and so some people would be glad to fix your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with without mixing your CSS and javascript concerns quiet so much. Here is an example that demonstrates what you trying to do:

**HTML**

```
<div class="hoverStyles">Hover Me!</div>
<button onclick="toggleHover()">Toggle hover</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.hoverStyles {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.hoverStyles:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue
}

.noHoverStyles {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggleHover() {
  if ($('.hoverStyles').length > 0) {
    $('.hoverStyles').addClass('noHoverStyles').removeClass('hoverStyles');
  } else {
    $('.noHoverStyles').removeClass('noHoverStyles').addClass('hoverStyles');
  }
}
```

[Edit] The pen below has been updated (see comments) so it's not exactly the same as the code in this answer anymore, both are still valid.

[Here is a working pen.](http://codepen.io/ozrevulsion/pen/MaRrvW)

Let me know if you have any further questions :D

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
I see your point, however i didnt include it in the code, but its supposed to attr the image on hover as well, so i believe i need jquery to handle both things on hover, am i right?

Comment: No, it's fine you can still do this with CSS. I've updated my pen to show how you can use the hover to change the picture that is being displayed. http://codepen.io/ozrevulsion/pen/MaRrvW

Comment: i see that your example is working, however im not sure i understand the jquery. 
i added
topnav #search:hover {
}
it doesnt however respond to hover, what exactly is it that the jquery code does? and does it still make the other functions that i made work?

ie. .length > 0

Comment: Ok, and what is the result? Not good I'm guessing based on your comment :) So what is happening? Are you getting no image? Are you able to update your fiddle with what you did so I can take a look?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e7pxt6to/

I didnt add the jquery code you suggested, as im unsure whats happening. I might be a little bit hard to work with, but i really want to understand whats going on :) especially the .length > 0 and what the conditional expression really does.

Comment: So all the query is doing is saying; Can we find any elements with the hoverStyles class on the page. If we do then change their class from hoverStyles to noHoverStyles. If we don't find any hoverStyles elements then change all the noHoverStyles elements to have the class hoverStyles. This, in reality, is fairly brittle code and you will probably want to change this to suit your needs but it serves to demonstrate the point for now. As for your hover not working I think your css selector should just be "#search:hover" not "topNav #search:hover" But an updated fiddle will help me diagnose that.

Comment: Again, thank you for letting me take your time, the code makes sense now. :-)
i can actually get it to work, but as you said the code is brittle, wouldnt it be smarter of me to let jqery take care of all the stuff that is happening?

Comment: Ok, here is your code and mine mixed together. http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/e7pxt6to/2/ Hopefully that's enough to help you understand the solution. That should be enough for you to be able to adapt the code to your needs. If this answer has helped you please don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as correct. Good luck!